# Qt - when has the UI finished initialization? So scroll bar positions etc can be set?

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a simple use case in a Qt app:

When the UI has been constructed and a `QGraphicsView` (or any other `QWidget`) has been populated, scroll the graphics view to a given location, based on the graphics views width and height (or any other attribute set by the layout engine).

However I can't find a reliable or known place to do this. In the constructors the layout has not yet been applied, so the width isn't the final width that the user sees once the UI is "up". Most suggestions seem to consist of hacks such as:

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(initWidget()));
```

In my case this doesn't seem to work unless I set the delay to around 10msec which seems even more risky and hacky. Surely there must be something like win32's `WM_INITDIALOG` or the likes?

Comment: What is wrong about the single shot static timer functionality? It looks good to me. I personally do not consider it as hack.

Comment: Because sometimes it doesn't work, I have to try 10,20,30msec etc, Its like adding a sleep() to fix a race condition. There must be something in the framework that supports this. Maybe a "layout complete" event or something, I dunno..

Comment: Well, just choose the biggest, but you could reimplement the showEvent(), too, as per the answer in [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/6530).

Answer (score 1):

You can override [`showEvent()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#showEvent) or [`resizeEvent()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#resizeEvent) of the relevant class.

After a bit of experimenting, since you say you're using `showMaximized()`, you actually may want to override both, and then get the size from first `resizeEvent()` after first `showEvent()` (or 2nd `resizeEvent()` overall). Output from my test app which used `showMaximized()`:

```
Starting /home/hyde/test/build-eventTest-Desktop-Debug/eventTest...
resizeEvent size QSize(200, 100) oldSize QSize(-1, -1) 
showEvent geometry QRect(0,0 200x100) 
resizeEvent size QSize(1440, 851) oldSize QSize(640, 480) 
/home/hyde/test/build-eventTest-Desktop-Debug/eventTest exited with code 0
```

---

Then do what you need to do there. If you want to do it just once, then add a boolean member variable like

```
bool mFullyInited;
```

and initialize it to false, and then in the overriden event handler method, test it and set it to true when you've done the initialization.

Comment: I'm using showMaximized() in my main() .. seems like a 2nd resize event is sent sometime later which is the real inited state? Still seems hacky to have to say if its the 2nd resize event then finish setting up the UI?

Comment: @paulm I did a bit of experimenting, and if first `showEvent()` still has wrong size for you, then you could do it in first `resizeEvent()` *after* first `showEvent()`. Not exactly pretty either, but I wouldn't call that "hacky", if that's just how the events go.

Comment: Any idea if this ordering is guaranteed?

Comment: @paulm Nope :-(. But I updated the answer with the actual output of my experiments. Anyway, this is the only way I know to do this without resorting to timers or something.

Comment: @paulm Actually, of course there are at least two more places to investigate, for putting the code: `paintEvent()` and `moveEvent()`...

Comment: I've had an idea, resizeEvent always happens, so I could say if the event is < 500msec since construction time then setup the widgets, else we're done.. still hacky though

Comment: I wouldn't use timer, at least not like that. I'd rather re-do the geometry-dependent part of init in first 2 resizeEvents, maybe 3 to be safe. And if Qt is changed so that there are more than that many resizes at program startup, I'd file a bug against Qt ;)

Comment: @paulm more thoughts: whatever the geometry dependent part is, would it make sense to write it so that you do it in every resize? Why is first show special? Or do it in every resize until user scrolls manually?

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is setting the scroll bar position in a QAbstractScroll after after the UI has been sized. I want to move it to the middle of the scroll area - but obviously not everytime the window resizes :)